# Apply function on each li with pure Js

Tags: javascript, loops

I have done a function that reads out the content of an element using the speech api, I am having a list of news like this

```
<ul id="news">
    <li>
How Instagram Is Winning Gold at the 2012 Olympics [INFOGRAPHIC]
   </li><li>
      Flickr Photo of Insect Identified As Never-Before-Seen Species [VIDEO]
   </li><li>
      The Upside to the End of the Olympics [COMIC]
   </li><li>
      40 Digital Media Resources You May Have Missed
   </li><li>
      19 Resources to Improve Your Photo and Video Skills
   </li><li>
      Top 10 Twitter Pics of the Week
   </li><li>
      Can Employees Be Trusted to Work From Home? [INFOGRAPHIC]
   </li><li>
      Capture Ghosts at Foursquare Spots With ‘Ghostbusters’ iOS Game
   </li><li>
      Dog Is Terrified of Low-Fat Lamb Jerky [VIDEO]
   </li><li>
      5 Tips to Take Food Photos Good Enough to Eat
   </li><li>
      The 10 Most Stunning Images of Mars in History
   </li><li>
      The Many Looks of Spiderman Over the Past 50 Years [INFOGRAPHIC]
   </li><li>
      Top Ten GIFs of the Week
   </li><li>
      Romney and Obama Both Called Their Veeps the ‘Next President’ [VIDEO]
   </li><li>
      Paul Ryan Visited Facebook, Met Zuckerberg [PICS]
   </li><li>
      Romney’s Logo Looks Like Toothpaste [PICS]
   </li><li>
      Paul Ryan, Romney’s VP Pick, Has Sizable Online Presence
   </li><li>
      Get Back in Kitchen With This Specialized Recipe Site
   </li>

</ul>
```

Now am reading out text using this function.

```
function speak() {
    //speechapi.speak(document.getElementById('start').innerHTML,"male");
    speechapi.speak(document.getElementById('start').innerHTML,"male");

}
```

How do i make it read each li with a small interval in between? I don't want to use jquery or like.
But I am not able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it, with a delay of 2 seconds between each line:

```
var news = document.getElementById('news').getElementsByTagName('li');

var newsItem = 0;
var speechInterval = setInterval(function(){
    speechapi.speak(news[newsItem].innerHTML, "male");
    if (++newsItem === news.length){
        window.clearInterval(speechInterval);
    }
}​, 2000);
```

[**DEMO, inserting text in a `<p>` tag instead of speaking it**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/r2dAd/)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
function speak() {
    var i = 0,
    li = document.getElementById('news').getElementsByTagName('li'),
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if (i < li.lenght){
            speechapi.speak(li[i].innerHTML,"male");
            i++;
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/window.setInterval

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on the problem:

```
function speak() {
    var li = document.getElementById ('news').getElementsByTagName ('li')
      , i = 0;

    li = [].slice.call (li, 0);

    (function speakItem() {
      speechapi.speak(li[i++].innerHTML, "male");
      i < li.length && window.setTimeout (speakItem, 1000);
    }
}
```

The `[].slice.call (li, 0)` converts the live list of li elements to a simple JS array, making for more efficient processing.

Each item is read, then, if there are more items, a 1 second interval is started before speaking the next one. This allows for long and short items with constant intevals between each.